# Crash with iOS 8 SceneKit Assets when building over command line

Tags: xcode, command-line, build, ios8, scenekit

I am building a 3D game over command line with. My script works for all other applications without a problem. Unfortunately the built IPA of the game crashes when I start it on my iPhone. If I build it with the Xcode GUI, it works fine. This error only appears for Xcode projects with SceneKit Assets.

Any idea how I can prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Xcode forgets to generate the scnassets when building on command line (xcodebuild). we fixed it with the following build rule:

[image]
**Script:**

${DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR}/../usr/bin/copySceneKitAssets "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${DERIVED_FILE_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_NAME}”

**Output Files:**

$(DERIVED_FILE_DIR)/${INPUT_FILE_NAME}